# Launch event on first click jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a possibility in jQuery to add event e.g `alert('hi');` for first click only ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you may use the [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) binding function :

```
myelement.one('click', function() { 
    alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: What if I want to use one click for 2 elements ? E.g `btn.a1` `btn.a2` ?

Comment: Then use `$('btn.a1,btn.a2').one('click', function() { alert('hi') });`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a boolean to check if it's the first click like this:

```
var clicked = false;

$(document).click(function() {
    if(!clicked){
          alert("hi");
          clicked = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jquery one binding solution  will be good for you as long the dom is not realoded. i.e the user is on the same page without refreshing.

if you need to use this including page reloading there are 3 ways:

1.using a DB
  2.using a Session
  3.using a Cookie

those are all server side solutions, allowing you to control the user click events.
if this is what you are looking for i will elabrate this and will write code examples.
if not the one binding suggestion is good.
hope this help.

Comment: What better solution than from @dystroy are you suggesting?

Comment: How is using a cookie a server-side solution? You can absolutely use cookies without any server-side involvement.

Comment: when setting a cookie on a user you can set your Vars so they will interact with your DB / Server Vars, so i consider this as a server side solution.